# how to identify incoming call using android?

Tags: android

I want to record incoming call,any body knows please give some idea about that,other wise give some idea about How to know about incoming call,

Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should write a broadcast receiver i.e. make a class and extend it from BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MyCLass extends BroadcastReceiver {
 // functions here
}
```

In the manifest.xml file write

```
<receiver android:name="MyClass">
            <intent-filter>             
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER">/action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

This will call your MyClass where ever a call will be received

Comment: Thanks Umairp,can you give elaborate idea about broad cast receiver,i don't know Broadcast recevier

Comment: Guys, it's impossible to record the audio on a call.

Comment: If you just want to get notified when there's an incoming call, then yes you can use a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @JohnNick: Its not a big deal actually. When you create an activity you are actually extending a class with Activity where as when you create BroadcastReceiver you extend a class from BroadcastReceiver (I wrote it above - its that simple). Although, I am not sure if you can record the call or not.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to record the call with the phone itself unless you are routing the call through a service that lets you record the call (see Google Voice, for example).

[ACTION_ANSWER](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER) for when a call is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is impossible to record a call. The streams are in the lower level operating system and don't transpire to the application level.